# PowerShell to SQL,simple enquiry

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am trying to pull data from a SQL database using PowerShell.

This is the SQL of what I am trying to do

`USE dbfile
SELECT *
FROM table.marker
WHERE table.marker = 0
ORDER BY table.sessionid`

How do I put this in to PowerShell?
My level of understanding for PowerShell is not bad but this is just out of my current knowledge zone and I just don't have the time resource to figure it out the old fashioned way..

Comment: Use [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/invoke-sqlcmd-cmdlet) or see [How do you run a SQL Server query from PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423541/how-do-you-run-a-sql-server-query-from-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you'd need a connection string somewhere in your powershell script such as:

```
$connectionstring= "SERVER=servername; database=databasename; user id=username;password=password
```

Then you'd need to append the query to a string something like:

```
$myQuery = 
@"
USE dbfile
SELECT *
FROM table.marker
WHERE table.marker = 0
ORDER BY table.sessionid
"@
```

Then you'd need to open an SQL connection with your query, create an SQL adapter with a dataset - something like:

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionstring
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $myQuery
$command.Connection = $connection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$myDataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($myDataSet)
```

Then you can call the dataset wherever you want using

```
$myDataset.Tables[0].rows (etc)...
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I'll give that ago in the morning :)