# Need help me with azure runbooks?

Tags: automation, azure-sql-database, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I want to schedule a simple task to truncate a table using the Runbook. The database is Azure SQL Database.

- What type of runbook should I create. How should I code it?
- Are there any sources to learn more about azure runbooks?

Comment: there is nothing to learn, its just powershell

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-runbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you could create a powershell runbook to execute [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

To invoke sql command via powershell, you could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423541/how-do-you-run-a-sql-server-query-from-powershell).

Sample:

```
function Invoke-SQL {
    param(
        [string] $dataSource = ".\SQLEXPRESS",
        [string] $database = "MasterData",
        [string] $sqlCommand = $(throw "Please specify a query.")
      )

    $connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource; " +
            "Integrated Security=SSPI; " +
            "Initial Catalog=$database"

    $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
    $command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)
    $connection.Open()

    $adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
    $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

    $connection.Close()
    $dataSet.Tables

}
```

For more details about Azure runbook, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types).

Comment: Thank you or the code. It helped me.

Comment: @DaxeshRadadiya If it is helpful, please mark it as the answer(on the left of my reply, there is an option to mark), thanks.

Comment: Done. Thanks for being around. :)