# How to properly use Export-Csv in this code

Tags: sql, powershell, export-to-csv

I used the code found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17497834/8918324 to make an SQL query that dosen't need to import the libraries for SQL.

The goal is having it run on a server and once a week pull the query and send it as a CSV table to my boss.

```bsh
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $ServerName, $DatabaseName, $ConnectionTimeout
$conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$conn.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($Query, $conn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout = $QueryTimeout
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ($cmd)
$da.Fill($ds)
$conn.Close()
$ds.Table
```

Expected is a result like Visitor number name visited ... in an CSV.
Depending where I put it it is eihter empty or just gives a table ID.

Where do I put the `Export-Csv` cmdlet?

Comment: when i run it without the export csv cmdlet, i get the resulst from the querry displayed in the console. but how do i get ist from the console in the csv?

Comment: `$ds.Table | Export-Csv ...`, obviously.

Comment: if put it there i don't get the sql querry results but rather infos about the table. sorry for the Late reply but i had an accident and spent the last few weeks in an hospital.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I hope you're feeling better now. Anyway, `$ds.Table` should probably be `$ds.Tables[0]`.

Comment: yes thanks it's solved