# VSTS/Azure Devops - Check if record exists in SQL Server as part of the CI/CD tasks

Tags: sql, sql-server, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Using TFS 2018. I have setup a build pipeline that builds my solution and executes all unit tests. I want to add a step on the end that queries a table in SQL Server and returns back a boolean value, if false, I would like to fail the pipeline and return an error.

I have seen many extensions that allow me to execute a script, but none that return data I can use to perform an action.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqlcmd.exe` from a Commandline/PowerShell Task to execute a query, then process the output in whatever way you want.

Similarly you can [use the standard .NET SqlConnection/SqlCommand classes in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18935548/736079) to execute a query and interpret the result. As [well as the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40510716/736079).

To pass or fail the build you can use the [Azure Pipeline Log commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to pass status back to the agent.

In Batch:

```
echo ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Your Message Here
```

Or in PowerShell:

```
Write-Output "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Your Message Here"
```