# Pass byte[] as parameter to sql insert script

Tags: sql, powershell, sqlcmd

I am trying to upload the binary[] of a Zip folder to my database. I used `Get-Content -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0` to read the data into a variable. I want to use this variable in an INSERT statement. Unfortunately, `sqlcmd` doesn't like the size of the variable, and gives me this error:

```
Program 'SQLCMD.EXE' failed to run: The filename or extension is too longAt line:1 char:1.
```

I have tried using the `-Q` option to run the query, and also `-i` to run a sql file.

---

```
DECLARE @data varbinary(MAX)
SET @data = '$(data_stuff)'

INSERT INTO MyTable
(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
VALUES
(v1,v2,v3,v4,@data)
```

---

```
sqlcmd -S servername -E -i .\file.sql -v data = "$binarydata"
```

---

Is there a workaround for doing this?

Comment: `sqlcmd` is not the best tool for working with binary-typed data, for example, it defaults binary results to 4000 bytes unless you specify `-Y 0`, and Microsoft warns against doing so here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL query/batch/`.sql` file, `binary`/`varbinary`/`image` literal data values must be in hexadecimal format with a `0x` prefix:

```
INSERT INTO tableName ( binaryColum ) VALUES ( 0x1234567890ABCDEF )
```

I don't know what the maximum length of a binary literal is, but I suspect things might stop working, or be very slow, if you exceed more than a few hundred kilobytes.

I recommend using ADO.NET directly via PowerShell, which will also let you use binary parameter values (`SqlParameter`): [How do you run a SQL Server query from PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423541/how-do-you-run-a-sql-server-query-from-powershell)