# Connect to multiple servers and databases and run the same SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sqlcmd

I have a fixed list of SQL Server 2019 (v15) Express databases, distributed across the country. I am hoping to script a way of querying them in a T-SQL batch. Have gotten as far as enabling SQLCMD and running this.

```
DECLARE @tsql nvarchar(500) = 'SELECT value FROM DB.dbo.Tablename'
    
:Connect EMS2410
GO

EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql

:Connect    EMS2411
GO

EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql
```

Without the `GO`, the connect statement does not work, with it I lose my variable. Looking for any ideas people may have for this situation. I could do a search and replace to patch in the actual SQL but that seems messy.

Comment: Did you tried add linked server and use sp_executesql remotely (exec linkedserver.master.dbo.sp_executesql @tsql)? You cannot change server connection in one session (its bounded to instance).

Comment: How about looping through your databases in a PowerShell script? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423541/how-do-you-run-a-sql-server-query-from-powershell

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried to connect to a different server with tsql. You can try testing this. Set up a table for the server names.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServerName](
    [SvrName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Svr] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SvrName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ServerName] ([SvrName]) VALUES (N'Server1')
INSERT [dbo].[ServerName] ([SvrName]) VALUES (N'Server2')
INSERT [dbo].[ServerName] ([SvrName]) VALUES (N'Server3')
INSERT [dbo].[ServerName] ([SvrName]) VALUES (N'Server4')
INSERT [dbo].[ServerName] ([SvrName]) VALUES (N'Server5')
GO
```

The carriage return isn't displaying it as I would like but it should work.

```
declare @sql1 varchar(max) = ''
declare @sql2 varchar(max) = ''
; with SvrNames as (
    SELECT [SvrName]
      FROM [DBName].[dbo].[ServerName]
)
select @sql1 = STRING_AGG(' :Connect ' + [SvrName] + ' GO ' + char(10) + char(13) + 'EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql ' + char(10) + char(13), '')
from SvrNames

select @sql2 = ' DECLARE @tsql nvarchar(500) = ''SELECT value FROM DB.dbo.Tablename''' + @sql1
--select @sql2
EXECUTE (@sql2)
```

The above script generates and executes the following.

```
DECLARE @tsql nvarchar(500) = 'SELECT value FROM DB.dbo.Tablename' 
 :Connect Server1 GO   
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql    
 
 :Connect Server2 GO   
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql    
 
 :Connect Server3 GO   
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql    
 
 :Connect Server4 GO   
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql    
 
 :Connect Server5 GO   
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be to create a separate script file - and then use that script file in each section:

```
:connect servername
:r {script file}
```

You can also set it up so your SQLCMD file builds the script - then each section executes the script - and at the end you delete the script:

```
:out C:\Temp\TempScript.sql
Set NoCount On;
Declare @sqlCommand nvarchar(max) = '';
Set @sqlCommand = '
   Set NoCount On;
   {build your script}
';

Select @sqlCommand;
Go
```

Calling that script file:

```
:setvar ScriptFile "C:\Temp\TempScript.sql"

:connect servername
:r '$(ScriptFile)'
Go
```

Then - delete the temp script file:

```
!!del '$(ScriptFile)'
```

With all that said - it would be much easier to use Powershell and Invoke-SqlCmd to loop over the list of servers and execute the query against each server.